# How to make a method transactional that is deleting and then writing to the database?

Tags: java, spring

If I have a method like this:

```
public void deleteAndCreateItem(final Item item)
{
   itemDao.delete(item); // delete from the database

   // Some business logic here to create a new item

   itemDao.store(newItem); //write to the database

}
```

How do I make the above method transactional so that if the `store` operation fails the delete operation rolls back.

*Note*: `delete()` and `store()` methods are marked as `@Transactional`.

I tried adding `@Transactional` annotation to the `deleteAndCreateItem()` method but it didn't work.

Comment: Adding @Transactional is what you need to do. But the application has to be properly configured, too. And that method must be the methd of a Bean. And it must be called from another bean. And the bean must indeed be a bean, i.e. created and injected by Spring. You've messed up somewhere, but it's hard to know where if you don't post all the relevant stuff.

Comment: Apart from adding @Transactional, you also need to make sure that the method `deleteAndCreateItem` is called from a class outside of this method's class. The annotation has no effect if another method from same class calls it.

Comment: In addition to the `@Transactional` annotation, you also need to have the `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation on a configuration class (or the main Spring Boot application class).